# 404 after deploying zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework, deployment, frameworks

I've deployed a zend application on a local server(ubuntu), the default page works fine, but all the rest of application throw the 404 not found page.

my index.php

```
    // Define path to application directory defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(), )));

/** Zend_Application */ require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run $application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini' ); $application->bootstrap()

            ->run();
```

application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0



resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"

resources.db.adapter = mysqli
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = assalam

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

_initAutoLoader function in the Bootsrap file

```
protected function _initAutoLoad(){
        $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                               'namespace'=>'',
                               'basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default'
                             ));
        if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
            Zend_Registry::set('role',Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read()->role);

        }else {
            Zend_Registry::set('role','Visiteurs');
        }

        $this->_acl = new Model_UsersAcls();
        $this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $fc->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($this->_acl));

        return $modelLoader;
     }
```

the apache2.conf contains

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the htaccess file contains

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

the virtual host code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your htaccess file set up?

Does your server allow htaccess files to be run (check that AllowOverride is set to All in your server configuration file).

As an example, here is the htaccess file from one of my projects:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !public/gateway/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is my .htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

Comment: i did it but now i can't access to the public folder, it's not visible and the Internal Server Error page appears

Comment: I put an example of one of my htaccess files here for you to compare to.

Comment: i put the htaccess content, i tried your code but the public folder wouldn't show up

Comment: thank you i solve it by activating the rewrite module in apache, thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy it? You used Zend Server Deployment? Have you setup a virtual host? What URL are you calling? What is the projects path?

Comment: I didn't use Zend Server
I have a machine that i use as a server, based on ubuntu server and apache. i copied all files to the www directory.  
the URL is 192.168.1.30, the application path is the default one "public", when i enter 192.168.1.30/public the front is desplayed, but when i want to navigate to other path like, 192.168.1.30/public/authentification/login the 404 page appear and it's the same to all other pages

Comment: Then its for sure AllowOverride. Your VirtualHost configuration must set AllowOverride to all see Elie's comment.

Comment: i did it but now i can't access to the public folder, it's not visible and the Internal Server Error page appears

Comment: Post your VirtualHost configuration, lets see what could be wrong.

Comment: i've added it on the request above, when i set the AllowOverride to All i obtain the other error page and the folder public isn't accessible any more, the application is in the /var/www/ folder

Comment: thank you i solve it by activating the rewrite module in apache, thank's a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have a virtual host, if not create something like this example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName helloWorld.dev
  DocumentRoot /Users/myuser/Sites/HelloWorld/public

  <Directory /Users/myuser/Sites/HelloWorld/public> 
      Options +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also on your hosts files

```
127.0.0.1       helloWorld.dev
```

I would recomend to check the folder permissions too

```
myuser:HelloWorld myuser$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  8 myuser  staff   272B Jan  6 11:54 application
drwxr-xr-x  3 myuser  staff   102B Jan  6 11:54 docs
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser  staff   136B Dec 28 20:54 library
drwxr-xr-x  4 myuser  staff   136B Jan  6 11:54 public
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser  staff   204B Jan  6 11:54 tests
myuser:HelloWorld myuser$ pwd
/Users/myuser/Sites/HelloWorld
myuser:HelloWorld myuser$
```

Add the following definition on the file /etc/apache2/users/myuser.conf. If this file don't exist create it

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: i don't know how to work with virtual host, because i have a machine that i use as a server, my application is in this root /var/www/, and the url is 192.168.1.30

Comment: i tried to add the virtual host but always the public folder doesn't appear, i put the code of the virtual host on the request

Comment: I experience the same problem with public folder long time ago I created a file on /etc/apache2/users called myuser.conf with the following definition                                             
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: thank you i solve it by activating the rewrite module in apache, thank's a lot for your help

Comment: No problem, just mark this questions as solved please.

Regards